# Band and bandgap

Tags: python

I am doing an assignment for class and have this question: "Create a target array `gap` for bandgap - the difference between `lumo_zindo` and `homo_zindo`." I do not understand or know what they are asking. In class, we simply learned how to plot multilinear regression so I have no clue what `gap` or `bandgap` are.

Comment: What class was this from? This seems to be a chemistry/physics/material science centric question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia goes a long way toward explaining your question about `lumo_zindo` and `homo_zindo`.
They're referring to electron orbitals.  HOMO is the Highest Occupied Molecular Orbital.  LUMO is the Lowest Occupied Molecular Orbital.  The Band Gap is the Energy delta between the two.

Check out the links for reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOMO_and_LUMO
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZINDO

As far as creating the `gap` Array in python (assuming `lumo_zindo` and `homo_zindo` are both lists that contain the same numeric data type), I'd try:

```
gap = []
for h,l in zip(homo_zindo, lumo_zindo):
    gap.append(h - l)
```